# Open Source Security Audit

Tags: audit

I recently forked a project on GitHub that had been abandoned, cleaned up a lot of the code and started to make improvements to it. As it's a forked project I'd like to find out what the best way to get the code audited for security is, so I can get any unknown issue's fixed.

Any advice is much appreciated.

BidFork: https://github.com/bidfork/BidFork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your project is PHP here's a list of [PHP static analysis tools](https://github.com/exakat/php-static-analysis-tools/blob/master/README.md). You run a static analysis which looks over the code for potential vulnerabilities. This is really the first step to catching obvious errors.

There are some commercial solutions that offer dynamic analysis, but I'm not aware if any for PHP which are free of charge.

Comment: excellent, thank you very much, from a quick look on the list the only one that I've been using which is on the list is PHP Code Sniffer, but everything else is new to me, I appreciate you sharing the list, plenty on there for me to use, thanks.